# Details of Pair-teaching system with untrained teachers

Tags: teaching-methods

I am trying to find details of a teaching system which I believe comes from one of the universities in Quebec, for teaching English and French.

It's an exchange technique: the students are organised into pairs, each learning the native language of the other.  The distinguishing characteristic is that they follow a particular course of materials prepared by the university, specifically designed for untrained teachers who are native speakers.

**My question is: does anyone have any references for this system or know of a place it is used or originated?**

*Context: I am TEFL-qualified teacher interested in teaching techniques.*